# How can i refresh data with setInterval when Actions.pop()?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create live dashboard mobile app with react-native. I `setInterval` to fetch data every 5 sec. When i go to other actions i `clearIntervar`(cause if i don't clear it continues other pages) and it's ok but when i try to `Action.pop(`) i cant `setInterval` again.

I tried to `setInterval` in `componentWillUnmount()` and `Action.refresh(with same props)` but every time; i get the same error.

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
>   componentWillUnmount method.

This is the sample like my code:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isRefresh: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData()
    }

    async getData() {
        //just a sample
        const data = await fetch(url).then((response) => response.json());
        this.setState({data: data});

        if (this.state.isRefresh) {
            const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                this.getData();
            }, 5000);

            this.setState({
                intervalId: intervalId,
                isRefresh: true
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.state.data}</Text>
                <Button onPress={() => {
                    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
                    Action.otherPage();
                    }
                } title={'Test Button'}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I have to setInterval and fetch data in the other pages too. So i need to clear when i go to other pages and need to `setInterval` when i come back with `Actions.pop()`

Comment: Just need to clarify, you have `isRefresh: false` in constructor and your if condition is `if (this.state.isRefresh){...}`. Where and how you are setting `isRefresh: true`, so that it enters the if condition in `getData` function?

Answer (score 0):

Don't store `intervalId` in state, instead you should make use of instance variable for your interval,

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       isRefresh: false
   }
   this.intervalId = null; //instance variable
}
```

Then assign your interval to instance variable,

```
this.intervalId = setInterval(() => { this.getData();}, 5000);
```

Then use `componentWillUnmount` to clear interval,

```
componentWillUnmount(){
 clearInterval(this.intervalId);
}
```

Comment: the problem is not clearIntervar.It's re set when comeback the action with Action.pop()

Comment: `Action.otherPage()` is navigating to other page right>

Comment: yes, but when i comeback to action with back button or Actions.pop() (react-native-router-flux) i need to setInterval(fetch and refresh data) again.

Comment: Then you should have `isRefresh: true` initially in constructor so that your setInterval will continue to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
componentDidMount() {
const { navigation } = this.props;
this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
  // The screen is focused
  // Call any action you want when a user on this screen
});
}
componentWillUnmount() {
// Remove the event listener
   this.focusListener.remove();
}
```

Comment: i am using router-flux. Can you write more spesiffic?